# Oblique random forest with ridge,svm, pls are resulting lesser accuracy than random forests

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, cart, artificial-intelligence

I am having 20 features with both discrete values and continuous values attributes. I am trying to compare the performance of random forest and oblique random forest. ORF usually performs better than RF but in our case RF is performing better than ORF. Any clarification and suggestion would be greatly appreciated. We used same parameters for all the models. Our class variable is a binary variable.

Comment: Because you are bootstrapping the coordinate-system as well as the columns and rows, you are going to need more trees, in general.  What can you tell us about the nature of the data, and what can you tell us about the parameters you are using?